# Javascript: Input after button click

Tags: javascript, html, input, formatting, styles

I was trying to figure out how to make a style editor for html. Like you can use here on stackoverflow the **bold** function. You can make text bold with the javascript function

```
str.bold();
```

This will bold the string you put in of course. I want to make it so when you click on a button the next things you type will be bold. When you click on it again the next thing you type will not be bold again.

I thought of some things. But all of them were not really possible.

Comment: Why not using something that is already out there?, check this out : http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/XNkDx/ it might be helpful.

Comment: Try an editable div. Good luck! :-)

Comment: Because i like making things my own. Second: The edit part is no problem. The problem starts when i want an easy **bold** function. Like I said: You click on a bold button the next things you wright are bold then. When you click on it again the next things won't be bold anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it can be easily implemented with an `editable div` and `document.execCommand('bold')`. You will have additional functionality like using keyboard shortcut (ie. ctrl+B), highlight and bold..

```css
#text {
    width : 500px;
    min-height : 100px;
    border : 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button id="toggle_bolt" onclick="document.execCommand('bold');">toggle bolt</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Very much! It just made my day this post